# What is Hoeffding's inequality in Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, random-variables, hilbert-spaces, functional-inequalities

Suppose I have random variables $X_1, X_2,...,X_n \in \mathcal{H}$, where $ \mathcal{H}$ is some Hilbert space. How can I bound the following term -

$ P(\| \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i - E[X_i]  \|_{\mathcal{H}} \geq \epsilon) $.

Answer (score 1):

Pages 53, 54 in [Gabor's Lugosi slides](https://www.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/de/for1735/prior-events/spring-school-2013/lecturer/slides-lugosi.pdf) from a while ago give the answer.